# C# Trouble changing a method after it has been defined

Tags: c#, methods, dice

I am very VERY new to all things coding, and I have run into a bit of trouble. I have this method that generates a random number between 1 - 6 (its supposed to simulate a dice roll), and what I want to do is through an input enable the user to change how many sides the dices has (The second parameter of the int nr in this case).

I want to be able to change the 7 to any number with a piece of code that is outside the method itself.
I can not wrap my head around how I am supposed to accomplish this.

```
static int RullaTärning(Random slumpObjekt)
{
    int nr = slumpObjekt.Next(1, 7); 
    return nr;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated, and if there is some piece of information missing that is needed to solve this, please let me know.

Thanks

I've tried changing the 7 to an integer variable "sides", but I don't know how to change this integer variable later on in the program.
I have tried a load of random stuff without much thought, but I don't know how to accomplish this at all. I really am lost.

Comment: Any further requirements? For example, Dice need _at least_ 6 sides? ... anything?

Comment: No. the user should be free to put any number they want.

Comment: Ok, what you have up until now is a fixed count of sides of ( 7 - 1 = ) 6 sides. What do you need in order to change that? For example, you wanted 16 sides? - You need to change the second parameter of `Next` to ( 16 + 1 = ) 17, right? So if the user wants n sides, that parameter needs to be ...

Comment: Yeah, thats right. I phrased my question really badly. i want to change the amount of sides with a piece of code that is outside the method.

Comment: _"I phrased my question really badly"_ - I see a lot worse 1st questions every day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You managed to realize that you need to somehow make the second param to `Next` method variable. Great! Let's do it:

```
static int RullaTärning(Random slumpObjekt)
{
    int sides = 6;
    int nr = slumpObjekt.Next(1, sides +1); 
    return nr;
}
```

now all you need to do is get the value from the user instead of hardcode it:

```
static int RullaTärning(Random slumpObjekt, int sides)
{
    int nr = slumpObjekt.Next(1, sides+1); 
    return nr;
}
```

If you do not want to force the user to choose a side-count (most dice would be 6-sided) you can work with a default:

```
static int RullaTärning(Random slumpObjekt, int sides = 6)
{
    int nr = slumpObjekt.Next(1, sides+1); 
    return nr;
}

// Can be used as
int roll = RullaTärning(rnd); // no second param => 6 will be used
// or
int damage = RullaTärning(rnd, 16);
```

I would always encourage to check your inputs:

```
static int RullaTärning(Random slumpObjekt, int sides = 6)
{
    // Assuming we had a requirement to allow no less than 6 sides.
    if( sides < 6 ) throw new ArgumentException("Dice need at least 6 sides.", nameof(sides));
    // Mind that I did not check `slumpObjekt` for null,
    // because a NullReferenceException will be thrown anyway
    // on the attempt to call `Next` on `null`.
    int nr = slumpObjekt.Next(1, sides+1); 
    return nr;
}

// because there is always "that guy" who will try
int nonsense = RullaTärning(rnd, -5);
```

... and a really pedantic fellow just made me mention clean code and "no magic numbers" ...

```
const int MINIMAL_ALLOWED_SIDES = 6; // Now we know why "6" and 
                                     // we only need to change 1 place in code 
                                     // if requirement of minimal allowed sides 
                                     // changes
static int RullaTärning(Random slumpObjekt, int sides = MINIMAL_ALLOWED_SIDES)
{
    if( sides < MINIMAL_ALLOWED_SIDES) throw new ArgumentException($"Dice need at least {MINIMAL_ALLOWED_SIDES} sides.", nameof(sides));
    int nr = slumpObjekt.Next(1, sides+1); 
    return nr;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, although there's no reason to require at least 6 sides, maybe throw if `sides < 1`.  Also standard would be to `throw new ArgumentException`

Comment: @PatrickMcDonald Number-of-sides requirement was only for demo purposes. About ExceptionTypes - I had hourly long discussions ... haha. But yeah, in the end I'd probably also choose `ArgumentException`.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help! I got everything working as it should =)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you this is simple method. Please go through basics

```
static int RullaTärning(Random slumpObjekt, int numberOfFaces){
int nr = slumpObjekt.Next(1, numberOfFaces+1); 
return nr;
}
```